# RPI4B OV5647 Camera black screen!

Tags: pi-4, raspicam, libcamera

Hi i recenlty bought a camera for my RPI4B but for some reason it's not working, whenever i enter libcamera-hello or rpicam-vid i get this error

```
new@raspberrypi:~/rpicam-apps $ rpicam-vid
[0:13:59.700932659] [3073]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:284 libcamera v0.2.0+46-075b54d5
[0:13:59.719660797] [3074]  WARN RPiSdn sdn.cpp:39 Using legacy SDN tuning - please consider moving SDN inside rpi.denoise
[0:13:59.722425283] [3074]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:447 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 to Unicam device /dev/media0 and ISP device /dev/media4
[0:13:59.722557469] [3074]  INFO RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1144 Using configuration file '/usr/local/share/libcamera/pipeline/rpi/vc4/rpi_apps.yaml'
Preview window unavailable
Mode selection for 640:480:12:P
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,640x480/0 - Score: 1000
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,1296x972/0 - Score: 1287
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,1920x1080/0 - Score: 1636.67
    SGBRG10_CSI2P,2592x1944/0 - Score: 1854
Stream configuration adjusted
[0:13:59.724585227] [3073]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1183 configuring streams: (0) 640x480-YUV420 (1) 640x480-SGBRG10_CSI2P
[0:13:59.725015990] [3074]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:611 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 640x480-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 640x480-pGAA
[0:14:00.843386065] [3074]  WARN V4L2 v4l2_videodevice.cpp:2007 /dev/video0[12:cap]: Dequeue timer of 1000000.00us has expired!
[0:14:00.843549492] [3074] ERROR RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1376 Camera frontend has timed out!
[0:14:00.843592566] [3074] ERROR RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1377 Please check that your camera sensor connector is attached securely.
[0:14:00.843636141] [3074] ERROR RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1378 Alternatively, try another cable and/or sensor.
ERROR: Device timeout detected, attempting a restart!!!
```

please i need help less than 3 weeks i have to finish a capstone project

note that i tried different other commands, i have followed the complete guide on this https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html#building-libcamera-and-rpicam-apps website and downloaded everything. still same error

heres my os

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```